# Alexa understand 24 hour

Tags: c#, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to build an Alexa skill that asks the user for an arrival time and I am expecting the answer to be in 24 hour format. So the user would say eighteen o five for 18:05.

I am struggling to find a way for Alexa to understand this without forcing the user down the 12 hour route.

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The [`AMAZON.TIME`](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#time) slot type is available but, unfortunately, doesn't work like you want.

If you're happy for users to say `"six fifteen pm"` it will pass a 24H time to your skill.

Answer (score 0):

This might be unconventional, but have you tried

[AMAZON.FOUR_DIGIT_NUMBER](http://AMAZON.FOUR_DIGIT_NUMBER)

If you think about it 24 hour format is also a 4 digit number

Comment: Thanks, tried that. but unfortunately, this falls apart when there is a zero in the minutes part. Most users will say eighteen o five for instance instead of eighteen zero five.

Comment: It looks like it might work if I break the intent into two slots, one for hours and one for minutes and populate the slot values so that it recognizes o five and passes o5 to my function where I can replace the o with an 0 and construct the 24 hour time there. Bit long winded, but think it will work. Haven't actually tested it yet though.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this in the end by using just the one custom slot type which takes the whole time in a malformed state. 18:05 comes in as 18o5. I then use a method within my code to tidy that up. Not the most scientific way to do this, but seems to work.